# What is an analog of UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In old MVC5/WebApi there was `UrlHelper` with static methods: `GenerateContentUrl` and `GenerateUrl`.
GenerateContentUrl was useful for getting url to app root:

```
var root = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~", context /*HttpContext*/);
```

In MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) we still have `UrlHelper` class. But there are no static methods in it.
So what to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Content` method on UrlHelper

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c1eea5b3fabb01d44fbf74f8fe64b4bd087bd576/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/UrlHelper.cs#L123

Example(from within a controller where Url property represents a UrlHelper): `Url.Content("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.css");`

A UrlHelper instance is created per-request and it gets the information about the application root path through the http context that gets injected into it.